# Capturing repeating sub-patterns with permutations in Python regex

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I am trying to tokenize a string made of sub-patterns that can appear in any order.
The sub-patterns are underscore, letters or numbers. For example:

```
   'ABC_123_DEF_456' would provide ('ABC', '_', '123', '_', 'DEF', '_', '456')
```

Here is the implemented regex giving the unexpected result:

```
>>> m = regex.match(r'^((_)|(\d+)|([[:alpha:]]+))+$', 'ABC_123_DEF_456')
>>> m.groups()
('456', '_', '456', 'DEF')
```

Updates:
- permutations: the three sub-patterns can appear in any order for example:

```
'ABC123__' would provide ('ABC', '123', '_', '_')
```

Comment: `re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z\d]+|_', 'ABC_123_DEF_456')` should work for you.

Comment: I added an update  above, the three token groups can appear in any order and multiple times, for example, the following should produce 4 tokens 'ABC', '123', '_', '_'

```
>>> re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z\d]+|_', 'ABC123__')
['ABC123', '_', '_']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `/([a-z]+|\d+|_)/i` to chunk the string into groups of digits, alphabetical characters or single underscores:

```
>>> re.findall(r"([a-z]+|\d+|_)", "ABC_123_DEF_456", re.I)
['ABC', '_', '123', '_', 'DEF', '_', '456']
>>> re.findall(r"([a-z]+|\d+|_)", "ABC123__", re.I)
['ABC', '123', '_', '_']
```